# Draw many (250 k) polylines (a trail)

Tags: android

I have to draw a trail that contains more than 250.000 polylines with more than 500.000 coordinates. For my mobile deca core (10) and android 6.0 it takes more 1 minute to draw trail and the map become very slowly.

Is there a solution to draw it more quickly with a fast map ?

Note:
The same approach is executed in iOS speedly without problem, it takes 3 seconds to draw and the map is super fast.
The same question exists, but the proposed solutions do not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

That is, perhaps, iOS doesn't draw all of them, obly approximated part, fitting current screen scale. You can do the same. 
Take maximal area, fitting current zoom and suggest, that there should not be more than 100 lines. Add approximation algorithm, using fewer key points and calculate new lines

Comment: iOS app draws all polylines (I have the app code (Swift)), my mission is to translate the iOS app to Android app !! Thx